# How to work with extra space for Varikon Tower?

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the Varikon Tower in python but getting trouble with the extra space this tower has.

I know Varikon Tower allows moves up only when the extra space is in that same column.
The code below is working for me well for a sliding puzzle like 15, and I have to keep the A* algorithm to solve it and see the moves I have to do to get the desire state (result).

This is what I have for now and it works, but can´t make it to Varikon Tower.

````
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

def puzz_astar(start,end):
    """
    A* algorithm
    """
    front = [[heuristic_2(start), start]] 
    expanded = []
    expanded_nodes=0
    while front:
        i = 0
        for j in range(1, len(front)):
            if front[i][0] > front[j][0]:
                i = j
        path = front[i]
        front = front[:i] + front[i+1:]
        endnode = path[-1]
        if endnode == end:
            break
        if endnode in expanded: continue
        for k in moves(endnode):
            if k in expanded: continue
            newpath = [path[0] + heuristic_2(k) - heuristic_2(endnode)] + path[1:] + [k] 
            front.append(newpath)
            expanded.append(endnode)
        expanded_nodes += 1 
    print ("Expanded nodes:", expanded_nodes)
    print ("Solution:")
    pp.pprint(path)


def moves(mat): 
    """
    Returns a list of all possible moves
    """
    output = []  

    m = eval(mat)   
    i = 0
    while 0 not in m[i]: i += 1
    j = m[i].index(0); #blank space (zero)

    if i > 0:                                   
      m[i][j], m[i-1][j] = m[i-1][j], m[i][j];  #move up
      output.append(str(m))
      m[i][j], m[i-1][j] = m[i-1][j], m[i][j]; 
      
    if i < 3:                                   
      m[i][j], m[i+1][j] = m[i+1][j], m[i][j]   #move down
      output.append(str(m))
      m[i][j], m[i+1][j] = m[i+1][j], m[i][j]

    if j > 0:                                                      
      m[i][j], m[i][j-1] = m[i][j-1], m[i][j]   #move left
      output.append(str(m))
      m[i][j], m[i][j-1] = m[i][j-1], m[i][j]

    if j < 3:                                   
      m[i][j], m[i][j+1] = m[i][j+1], m[i][j]   #move right
      output.append(str(m))
      m[i][j], m[i][j+1] = m[i][j+1], m[i][j]

    return output


def heuristic_2(puzz):
    """
    Manhattan distance
    """  
    distance = 0
    m = eval(puzz)          
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if m[i][j] == 0: continue
            distance += abs(i - (m[i][j]/4)) + abs(j -  (m[i][j]%4));
    return distance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    puzzle = str([[1, 2, 6, 3],[4, 9, 5, 7], [8, 13, 11, 15],[12, 14, 0, 10]])
    end = str([[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11],[12, 13, 14, 15]])
    puzz_astar(puzzle,end)
   # puzz_breadth_first(puzzle,end)```
````

Answer (score 2):

I'am doing just the same thing, solving Varikon Tower with A* and with the same heuristic.
I treat the varikon tower as a matrix where the content of each position indicate which color they are now or if they are empty. Then, for the "top layer" which has only one position which can "switch columns" I created a tuple that indicates the column where it is and its content, the color or "empty". The result is something like this:

```
state = ((t_col, t_content),
         [[l0_c0, l0_c1, l0_c2, l0_c3],
          [l1_c0, l1_c1, l1_c2, l1_c3],
          [l2_c0, l2_c1, l2_c2, l2_c3],
          [l3_c0, l3_c1, l3_c2, l3_c3]])
```

where lx_cy is the content on layer x from top to bottom and y is the column number, and t_col is the column where the top layer space is and t_content is its content